# Filter with SQL Server by Group ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

I have two tables and I need to filter the data by filter id depends on the relation to to filter group id.

For example I have this two tables:

Table 1:

| ItemID | FilterID |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 122 |
| 3 | 123 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 17 | 123 |

Table 2:

| FilterID | FilterGroupID |
| --- | --- |
| 122 | 5 |
| 123 | 5 |
| 4 | 1 |

- If I search by filter id = 123 than all item id with this filter need to be returned.
- If I search two or more different filter id that have different group id I need to get only the item ids that have all filter id and group id.

Desired output:

- first input: 123 -> return item id =3 and item id = 17
- second input: 123,4 -> return item id = 3 because filter id 123 belong to group id 5 and filter id 4 belong to group id 1 and item id 3 is the only one that has this two filters.
- third input: 122,123 -> return item id =3 and item id = 17 because both filter id belong to same group.

I am getting a little lost with this query and I will be glad to get some help.

I’ll try to simplify it: Let’s say we have group filter of size and group filter of color. If I filter by size S or M than I need to get all items with this sizes. If I want to add color like blue than the answer will cut the result by: item with size S or M and Color blue. So filter from different group may cut some results

Comment: Can you please share output and sample data in a formatted form. It is hard to understand as of now

Comment: I fail to understand how `Table2` and `FilterGroupID` are at all relevant to the question. Effectively you just need relational division between `Table1` and your list of filters. Which group they fall in is irrelevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you want to get every `ItemID` which has *at least one* matching filter from *each* `FilterGroupID` within your filter input. So within each group you have `or` logic, and between groups you have `and` logic

If you store your input in a table variable or Table-Valued parameter, then you can just use normal relational division techniques.

**This then becomes a question of [*Relational Division With Remainder*](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/learn/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/), with multiple divisors.**

There are many ways to slice this cake. Here is one option

- Join the filter input to the groups, to get each filter's group ID
- Use a combination of `DENSE_RANK` and `MAX` to get the total distinct groups (you can't use `COUNT(DISTINCT` in a window function so we need to hack it)

  - You can change this step to use a subquery instead of window functions. It may be faster or slower
- Join the main table, and filter out any `ItemID`s which do not have their total distinct groups the same as the main total

```sql
SELECT
  t1.ItemID
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      TotalGroups = MAX(dr) OVER ()
    FROM (
      SELECT
        fi.FilterID,
        t2.FilterGroupID,
        dr = DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY t2.FilterGroupID)
      FROM @Filters fi
      JOIN Table2 t2 ON t2.FilterID = fI.FilterID
    ) fi
) fi
JOIN Table1 t1 ON t1.FilterID = fi.FilterID
GROUP BY
  t1.ItemID
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT FilterGroupID) = MAX(fi.TotalGroups);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f6d3dc69494b1243c63628e952933c70)

Comment: The group id is relevant in order to know if need to add item because they filtered by same filter with same group or if different group take only items who exists in all groups. Basically the query should say: add all items that has filter that exists in same group or cut them of groups are different and take only those who lived on all groups. I hope this explain better my situation. Can you also please check my examples?

Comment: I’ll try to simplify it: Let’s say we have group filter of size and group filter of color. If I filter by size S or M than I need to get all items with this sizes. If I want to add color like blue than the answer will cut the result by: item with size S or M and Color blue. So filter from different group may cut some results

Comment: Ah I think I understand: so each item must match at least one of each filter group? Every filter group must be matched at least once, but not every filter?

Comment: Almost, if the input that I get(filter id) is from different group than items must be in all of this group and filters(basically using “and” statement by group id), otherwise(filter if input is from same group) get all items by filter Id (“or” statement by filter id)

Comment: So if your filter list is "size S, size M, color blue, color orange" you want items to be size S *or* M, *and also* either color blue or orange? So within each group you have `or` logic, and between groups you have `and` logic?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what i need and looking for

Comment: OK have modified, I think we have it correct now

Comment: thank a lot you saved me with this one, it works amazing. I am not sure I really understanding how it works but I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: If it helped you then you can upvote and/or accept it (by clicking the check mark).

Comment: @TProgram It works by using a combination of `DENSE_RANK` and `MAX` to get the total distinct groups in the filter input, as a window function. Then we join all the item filters, group them and check they have the same number of distinct groups